# passing JSON object to a web service through AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-asynctask

I am trying to pass a `JSON` object to a web service through `Asynctask`. I call a `collectStatistics` method in the `MainActivity`. This method collects some statistics of the mobile device and combines them together in a `JSON` object. `JSON` object is then passed to `Asynctask`.

```
    JSONObject jsonProperties = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonProperties.put("_device" , _device);
        jsonProperties.put("_model", _model);
        jsonProperties.put("_product", _product);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (jsonProperties.length() > 0)
    {
        //call to async class
        //String.valueOf(jsonProperties)
        //new SendJsonProperties().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, jsonProperties); //instead of execute
        Toast.makeText(context,jsonProperties.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
            new SendJsonProperties().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, jsonProperties);
            Log.i("msg","calling asynctask");
        } else {
            new SendJsonProperties().execute(jsonProperties);
            Log.i("msg","NOT calling asynctask");
        }
    }
```

**The Asynctask receives JSON parameter**

```
class SendJsonProperties extends AsyncTask <JSONObject,String,String>
```

**I call a web service caller method in doInBackground**

```
  protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... params)
{
    //(...) elippsis make the input array
    Log.i("msg", "do in bkgnd");
    WebServicesCaller webServicesCaller = new WebServicesCaller();
    result = webServicesCaller.storeStatistics(params[0]);
    return null;
}
```

**But I get this error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: {"_product":"ms013gxx","_model":"SM-G7102","_device":"ms013g"}
```

I cannot figure out the problem in serialization. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to send a JSON object to a web method which takes a string parameter

`public string storeStatistics(string jsonObj)`

So I changed

```
jsonProp.setType(JSONObject.class);
request.addProperty(jsonProp, obj);
```

to

```
jsonProp.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
request.addProperty(jsonProp, obj.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make Model POJO class of your JSONObject parameters.
Use this link to create POJO class according to JSON REsponse.

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you are talking about, could you please explain more? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you got this error because your objects(_product) is not serialized. for that you must convert that to serializable, by using above link, you get serialized objects